# Replace values occuring once in raster by NA

Tags: r, arcgis

I have vector of values(generated from raster - Raster package - by function **clump** in R):

```
values(rc)

1 NA NA NA  2 NA  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2 NA  2  2 NA  2  2 NA NA NA
NA NA NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA  3 NA  4 NA  2 NA  2 NA  5 NA NA  3 NA NA  4
NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA  6 NA  7 NA  4 NA NA
NA  8  8 NA  6  6 NA NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4  4  4 NA NA  9
NA NA NA NA 10 NA NA NA NA  4 NA  9  9 NA NA NA NA 10 NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA
9 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 11 NA NA NA 12 NA NA NA NA
```

and I would like to find **every value which occurs only once**(so 1,5,11,10) and **replace it by NA**. What I would like to obtain:

```
values(replaced_rc)

NA NA NA NA  2 NA  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2 NA  2  2 NA  2  2 NA NA NA
NA NA NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA  3 NA  4 NA  2 NA  2 NA  NA NA NA  3 NA NA  4
NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA  6 NA  NA NA  4 NA NA
NA  8  8 NA  6  6 NA NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4  4  4 NA NA  9
NA NA NA NA 10 NA NA NA NA  4 NA  9  9 NA NA NA NA 10 NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA
9 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

The problem is that I can easily identify **raster patches** by function **clump**. And I would like to exclude patches containing only pixel, similarly like function "sieve" in ENVI or ERDAS. Any help? Thanks a lot in advance.

Exemple from R:

```
library("raster")
r <- raster(ncols=12, nrows=12)
set.seed(0)
r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))*0.7 )
plot(r)
rc <- clump(r)
replaced_rc<- ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `duplicated`:

```
values(rc)[!duplicated(values(rc)) & !duplicated(values(rc),fromLast=T)] <- NA
```